# Image link as foreach images as $image

Tags: php, html, regex

Help please to form a link to the image. I have helper.php with code:

```
<?php
class modFliperImgsHelper {
  // check if directory exists
  if (is_dir(JPATH_BASE.DS.$folder)) {
    $files = modFliperImgsMegaHelper::getFiles($folder,$substoo,$random);
    $i = 0;
    $repeated = 0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      if (modFliperImgsMegaHelper::isImage($file)) {
        $file = str_replace( '\\', '/', $file );
        $images[$i] = JHTML::_('image', $file, '', $attribs);
        $repeated++;
        ++$i;
      }
    }
  }
  return $images;
}
?>
```

And I have Template for displaying images (listing or folder)

```
<?php if ($source==1) {  ?>
  <div id="myflipper">
  <?php
  $image1 = explode("\n",$image);
  for ($i=0;$i<count($image1);$i++) { ?>
    <div class="flipper-page no-padding">
      <a href="<?php echo $image1[$i]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image1[$i];?>" class="fullsize"></a>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php }  else  { ?>
  <div id="myflipper">
  <?php foreach ( $images as  $image ) { ?>
    <div class="flipper-page no-padding">
      <?php echo $image;?>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The second option in the template displays pictures from the folder, $ image; How To form a link to the image? I will be grateful for help
Here Screenshot 
[image: module list or folder]

Comment: What is the actual and expected output ?

Comment: Source == 1 (choose folder or list) image1[$i] (list of images, define the image path), echo $image (all images from folder)

Comment: How to create a link to <?php echo $image;?>, for example <a href=""><?php echo $image; ?></a>

Comment: I do not understand. you have that code already

Comment: Not quite! I need to get a link to image(s) from a folder in this part of code <?php foreach ( $images as  $image ) { ?> <a href="image.jpg"><?php echo $image; ?></a><?php } ?>

Comment: I attached a screenshot